# Windows Store App Button Click Event Not Firing with Grid Template

Tags: button, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I created a project using the default Grid Template with VS2012, and added a button to the upper right hand corner and it is NOT clickable, and if I remove the GridView then it's clickable.  Strange to me, could someone point out why this is the case

```xml
<Grid Style="{StaticResource LayoutRootStyle}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="140"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!-- Back button and page title -->
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Button x:Name="backButton" Click="GoBack" IsEnabled="{Binding Frame.CanGoBack, ElementName=pageRoot}" Style="{StaticResource BackButtonStyle}"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="pageTitle" Text="{StaticResource AppName}" Grid.Column="1" IsHitTestVisible="false" Style="{StaticResource PageHeaderTextStyle}"/>
        <Button 
            x:Name="SettingsButton"
            Grid.Column="2"
            HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
            VerticalAlignment="Center" 
            Margin="0,0,120,0" 
            AutomationProperties.Name="Settings" 
            Content="Settings"
            Click="SettingsButton_Click"
              />
    </Grid>

    <GridView .... />
</Grid>
```

Comment: In which page of default Grid Template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your GridView is being drawn on top of your button grid. Move the button grid declaration below the GridView.

```
<Grid Style="{StaticResource LayoutRootStyle}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="140"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!-- Move the GridView Here -->
    <GridView .... />

    <!-- Back button and page title -->
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Button x:Name="backButton" Click="GoBack" IsEnabled="{Binding Frame.CanGoBack, ElementName=pageRoot}" Style="{StaticResource BackButtonStyle}"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="pageTitle" Text="{StaticResource AppName}" Grid.Column="1" IsHitTestVisible="false" Style="{StaticResource PageHeaderTextStyle}"/>
        <Button 
            x:Name="SettingsButton"
            Grid.Column="2"
            HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
            VerticalAlignment="Center" 
            Margin="0,0,120,0" 
            AutomationProperties.Name="Settings" 
            Content="Settings"
            Click="SettingsButton_Click"
              />
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```